# EF5 one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

it is possible to be done using EF5?

`X` has many `Y`
`Y` has one `X` (one for many relationship)

however, `Y` has a second `X` that has no relation with the first `X`

is this possible?

```
public class X
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Y> Ys { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int id_X { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_X")]
    public X X { get; set; }

    public int id_X2 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_X2")]
    public X X2 { get; set; }
}
```

---

did not work.

The code looked like this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new context())
        {
            var x = context.X.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}

public class context : DbContext
{
    public context()
        : base(@"server=localhost\ALTAIRNOTESTI; uid=sa; pwd=13509; database=DDD")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<X> X { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Y> Y { get; set; }
}

public class X
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Y> Ys { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int id_X { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_X")]
    [InverseProperty("Ys")]
    public X X { get; set; }

    public int id_X2 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_X2")]
    public X X2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try? what is the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to tell EF that `X.Ys` and `Y.X` (and not `Y.X2`) belong together in a single one-to-many relationship, for example by using the `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
[ForeignKey("id_X")]
[InverseProperty("Ys")]
public X X { get; set; }
```